# Use contentObserver in manifest file

Tags: android, contentobserver

I am making an android app in which I want to get the call logs of all incoming, outgoing and missed calls and i am using content observer for this but i don't know that how to use content observer in manifest file. can anyone help me how to do this... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content Observer are never implemented in Manifest file Dy run when they got fired..

Answer (score 1):

Content observers are not supported in `AndroidManifest.xml` files. If in doubt whether some feature is supported or not, you can consult this page: [The AndroidManifest.xml File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)